# Checking if key is present in a map as "if statement" condition

Tags: go

I was solving katas on codewars and stumbled accross a way of checking if map has value associated with a given key. The code below is my own dummy example that returns (in a very inefficient way) "bar" string if function parameter is equal to 10.

I'm having hard times understanding how the `if` statement works here.

```
func Bar(x int) string {

    var m = make(map[string]int)

    if x == 10 {
        m["bar"] = x
    }

    if _, ok := m["bar"]; ok {
        return "bar"
    }

    return "foo"
}
```

If I make `if` statement look like this (removing `_`)

```
if ok := m["bar"];ok {
```

The code won't run, but I have no idea why. I don't know if this pattern is appropriate and the mechanisms behind it. For now it looks like a dirty trick as `if` evaluates only boolean expressions. So my theory is that the `_` somehow makes `if` statement think that it has a boolean condition, but I'd very much appreciate if someone guided my in the right direction

Comment: Basic language features are explained in detail in the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can read a value from a map. First is:

```
x:=m[key]
```

This will check if `m` has a value for `key`, and it will assign a copy of that value to `x` if so. If not, `x` will have its zero value. So if `m` is a, say, map[int]int, then `x` will have 0 if key is not in the map. This is not distinguishable from `m` having 0 for the given key.

You can use the second form of map read:

```
x, ok:=m[key]
```

If `m` has a value for `key`, this will set `x` to that value, and set `ok` to true. If `m` does not have a value for `key`, this will set `x` to its zero value, and set `ok` to `false`.

In `if _,ok:=m["bar"]; ok`, the `_` ignores the value returned from the map, but whether or not the map contains the key is now known from the value of `ok`. The if statement first evaluates an assignment, then checks the condition, which is here the boolean value `ok`.

In short, that if statement checks if the key is in the map, and if so, does something.